# multiple css animations per element doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate `.circle` element. It should grow and then shrink after second. So I declared 2 css animations for one element. In Firefox it works great, but in Chrome it doesn't.

[Can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_animation) shows that `animations` css rule in Chrome should work too.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/nrzull/pen/KKwOxEz)

Full source code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes one {
  100% {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes two {
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  /** If declare only one animation, then it will work in Chrome */
  animation: one ease 1s alternate 1 paused, two ease 1s alternate 1 paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
  circle.style.animationPlayState = "running, paused";

  setTimeout(() => {
    circle.style.animationPlayState = "paused, running";
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misinterpreting what you're trying to accomplish, but why don't you just do one animation and set the 5000px width and height at 50%? @keyframes grow { 50% { width: 5000px; height: 5000px; } }

Comment: One thing is you have a delay on both animations that doesn't have a unit, right before you right `paused` you have `1` there with no units. Another thing is that your animations seem to be opposing each other. As the comment above suggests, doing this with one animation would be cleaner and easier.

Comment: @StephenMIrving it's not the delay but the `animation-iteration-count` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, if you are correct and OP meant for that to be the `animation-iteration-count` rather than delay, then why include it at all? That property defaults to `1` so having it there is redundant.

Comment: @StephenMIrving in all the cases it's not the delay, more than that it's related to the OP thinking. I don't know why it's there but it's valid.

Comment: I cannot speak for OP, but it made sense to me that it would be a mistake trying to add delay because it would make sense to want to delay the start of the animation for a second after page load and then delay the start of the shrinking part of the animation. Obviously the browser is going to try to interpret it as a unitless property because there are no units. But adding `1` there, while valid, doesn't really make any logical sense because it does nothing. Whatever his intent, it is a mistake either way.

Answer (score 0):

So as one of the comments says, you can do this with a single animation. You should always try to use semantic, meaningful names when coding so I named the animation `grow-shrink` rather than just `one`.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes grow-shrink {
  50% {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 5000px;
  }
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  animation: grow-shrink 2s;
}
```

You don't need any of the JavaScript to do this and you don't need the `z-index` property on `.circle`. I changed your animation-duration to be `2s` rather than `1s` since it is doing the work of both `1s` animations you had initially. The `animation-timing-function` initial value is already `ease`, so I removed that because it is redundant. You also didn't need the `alternate` value.

If you meant the `1` after `alternate` in your `animation` value as the the value for `animation-iteration-count` then that can be safely removed as that property's initial value is already `1`. If you meant it as a `1s` delay for the grow animation to start and then another 1s delay for the shrink to start and simply forgot the units then you will have to let me know and I will show you how to modify it to do that. You can easily add the `1s` delay for the animation start back in there, but delaying the shrinking would have to be done differently if you use this solution.

Here you can see the [Codepen of it working](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/eYmqoVd).

---

**EDIT: Solution #2**

Alternately, if you want to see how to get this done using your method (though I wouldn't recommend it for this particular animation), here is the CSS code after I got your example to work in Chrome (and all other major browsers):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    height: 5000px;
    width: 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    height: 5000px;
    width: 5000px;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  animation:
    grow 1s ease-in forwards paused,
    shrink 1s ease-out 1s forwards paused;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}
```

Go here to see [the CodePen of solution #2 working](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/eYNOGGe).

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't explain why my example doesn't work in Chrome despite its feature support.

Comment: Multiple animations do work in Chrome, I have used the feature many times in production applications. Particularly when using the `animation` shorthand property though, it can not always be intuitive as to how to structure your animations to get them to work the way you envision. I am not sure exactly how to alter your specific example in order to get it to work that way, but given that this particular problem is easier done with a single animation, does tinkering with it really matter?

Comment: @nrzull check the edit to my post, I got your original code working in Chrome using your method, if you are curious as to what it looks like working.